# Is there a way to open windows command CLI from Windows Explorer with Administrator rights?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer

In windows explorer, you can open a folder and type "cmd" in the address bar. 
Then a CLI (cmd) is opened with the CWD set to the path that was selected in Windows Explorer. But this is not run as Administrator.

Is there something similar for opening cmd with Administrator rights?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've learned to handle this is to go to the root path (C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe), create a shortcut to your desktop. On the shortcut, go to properties, advanced, check the box "run as administrator".

or

> Type cmd, from Start, as Administrator. As follows:

1. Click **Start**.
2. In the **Start Search** box, type **cmd**, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.
3. If the **User Account Control** dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click **Continue**.

Comment: and if you don't want to keep anything on your desktop, you can run a non-privileged `cmd` from anywhere, then when that shows up on the  taskbar, click on that to get pop up a menu, and then on the `Command Prompt` line on that menu, right click to get the `Run as Administror`

Comment: @infixed Nice trick. I did't know that one. But you gave me an idea.. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER trick doesn't work, it opens a normal console.

Comment: @ths You're right. I'm so used to Win+R, it's in the Start command box. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a toolbar shortcut with the following command:

`C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /TN "AdminCommandPrompt"`

Create a schedule task called `AdminCommandPrompt` that runs with the highest privilege, Action a command called `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe`, and allow it to be run on demand. Then create a shortcut that you call the scheduled task.

More details:

This is how your Task Scheduler task should look like:

[image: Task Scheduler AdminCommandPrompt]

[image]

[image]

Then create a new shortcut with the following command:

`C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /TN "AdminCommandPrompt"`

Then call the shortcut AdminCP. If you run it, you should get an Admin Command Prompt without the UAC. If you change the icon, I can't get focus on the console for some reason.

Comment: Nope.  Not working.  It looks like that should run a task called "AdminCommandPrompt".  As I don't have such a task already installed, this isn't working well.  I'm using Win7 x64; if your technique works but only in another version of Microsoft Windows, then that should be mentioned.  Perhaps your directions would work on some systems where preparation has already been made, but, as is (when this question hasn't yet been edited), these directions seem incomplete.

Comment: @TOOGAM yes are you right. I may have omitted some details. Please try again. Screenshots included.

Answer (score 1):

This regedit file will create the appropriate context menu shortcut to the shift-rightclick context menu: (courtesy [sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/47415-open-command-window-here-administrator.html))

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00   

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here as Administrator"
"Extended"=""
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here as Administrator"
"Extended"=""
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
@="Open command window here as Administrator"
"Extended"=""
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""


[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\runas]
"Extended"=""
"HasLUAShield"=""
@="Open command window here as Administrator"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

The magic lies in the `HasLUAShield` keyword.
(Remove the `Extended` lines if you want it in the regular context menu)

Answer (score 0):

### Depending on your Windows version, there are a few possible ways:

#### Windows - 8 / 8.1 / 10

Right-click on the **Start Menu** icon
Choose the option **`Command Prompt (Admin)`**

#### Windows - Vista / 7 / 8 / 8.1 / 10

Open the **Start Menu**
Type *cmd* in the **Search Bar**
When the respective icon appears, right-click it and **`Run as Administrator`**

#### Generic method among most Windows versions

Go to **`C:\Windows\System32`**
Search for **`cmd.exe`**
Right-click it and choose **`Send to -> Desktop (Shortcut)`**
Return to the **Desktop** where you shall right-click the shortcut and choose **`Properties`**
**`Compatibility`** tab
Tick the **`Run as administrator`** option
Apply & Ok

***P.S.: Doing it through the Windows Explorer is much harder to do since these methods are so much more accessible***

Comment: OP does not just want to open the cmd as admin. He wants to open it with a specific cwd (current working directory) that he has currently opened in the Windows Explorer.